# How can i change borderbrush of checked Radiobuttons in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have set of radio buttons when either of them are checked as true i want to change their border brush to "Aqua" while getting back to checked as false border brush to be black 
i wanna do that in XAML neither in vb.net nor in C#...

```
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. XP" IsChecked="True" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="50"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. 7"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. 8"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="10"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Office Xp"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2007"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2003"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Thanx In Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Triggers for this purpose

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. XP" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. 7"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="OS" Content="Win. 8"/>
    <StackPanel Margin="10"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Office Xp"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2007"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2003"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: +1, though, there is no point of having both a True and False. You can have just a True (or False) trigger, and have the default Style as the color you want.

Comment: @d.moncada Oops, you're right. Redundant trigger removed. :)